# Oracle database won't connect day after connection worked. I can connect in SQL Plus but not in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

The other day I made an Oracle database and connected to it via Oracle SQL Developer. Now when I go back to SQL Developer and put in my password this error appears. "The Network Adapter could not establish the connection". I am not sure what to do as the connection worked the other day with nothing extra except just the username and password. I checked and I can connect to the same database via my SQL Plus.

I am NEW! Like this is my first ever Oracle database connection. So please bear in mind I am a noob.

I tried recreating the connection and still does not work. I'm so new that anything on google looks/sounds like garble so I'm in dire need of assistence.

Comment: you need two things to be able to connect with sql developer, the database needs to be running AND the listener needs to be running. Are you running Oracle DB on windows or linux?

Comment: you can also try a 'bequeath' type connection if sqldev is on the same machine as the database, this will be approximately the same as how sqlplus is working for you

Comment: I would guess that you rebooted your PC and got a different IP address; and that your `listerner.ora` is configured with the IP address not hostname (your PC name). It would be helpful to edit your question to include your connect information (the hostname, port and service name), and the contents of your `listener.ora` and `tnsnames.ora`, all as formatted text. And if you can log into the database as SYS, the `local_listener` setting.